# HMVC Modules array Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have array in my config and I get it to foreach. It works ok but how can I get parameter from any modules. For example I want parameter 1 to custom/custom/index.

Thank you for reply

```
$config['modules'] = array('calendar/calendar/index','randphoto/randphoto/index','feedback/feedback/index','survey/survey/index','custom/custom/index');

foreach ($this->config->item('modules') as $key) {
        echo Modules::run($key);
      }
```

If I try alone, it works fine but I want it in array echo `Modules::run('custom/custom/index', 1);`

Comment: use $this->uri->segment(3); This will give you the third parameter coming from url. For more read the user guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$this->uri->segment(3);` This will give you the third parameter coming from URL. For more read the user guide

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html